# How to init mysql in docker with correct time_zone_name table?

Tags: mysql, docker

Is there anyway to init MySQL with specific tables for time zone?

I am trying to use MySQL 5.7 on docker with image `mysql:5.7` and `Asia/Hong_Kong` is used as timezone name in the application. But on the default table `mysql.time_zone_name` built on the docker image only contains:

- posix/HongKong
- right/Asia/Hong_Kong
- right/Hongkong

I understood that I could manually [Populating the Time Zone Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) with
`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql`
or through given SQL on `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html`

As I am using `default_time_zone='Asia/Hong_Kong'` in mysqld in my.cnf, this would be a fatal error as Asia/Hong_Kong do not exist at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ENV in your Docker-Compose file

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
      - TZ=Asia/Hongkong
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--default-time-zone=+09:00']
```

Comment: Thank you and this works. I have upvoted but it wont occur until I have enough reputation. Sorry if that bothers you.